# A way to search Google Photos for photos not shared, or not in a specific album?

Tags: google-photos

Is there a way to search Google Photos for photos that:

Are not shared, for example in a shared album.

or

Are not in a specific, given album.

This SE question is similar but not the same: [How can I view Google Photos that are not in a Google Photos album?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/82693/how-can-i-view-google-photos-that-are-not-in-a-google-photos-album)