# How to organize Google Photos?

Tags: google-photos

Is there any good way to organize photos into albums in Google Photos? I use photos for a lot of quick documentation and I need to organize them for efficient recall.

I'm trying to filter the ones I want to save into a temp folder and then sort them into specific folders. I select the ones I want to save and add them to an album. However, once they're added, I can bulk archive the others, but the saved photos are stuck in that album. There is no way to move photos from one album to another, only copy them to another album label.

I can add photos to albums (and now archive photos), but there isn't a way to do both without selecting the same 100+ photos over again. Nor is there a way to filter in the search box like in GMail for is:archived, or label:Saved.

The only workaround is to view each one in an album and unarchive (ctrl-a), but there is a significant lag. Once they are back in the 'Timeline', I can put them in a specific folder.

(I've tried moving selected items to the trash, archiving the others, and then restoring from the trash, but they don't get restored to the Timeline, they stay archived. I think that's all of the logic possible for organizing, beside selecting each photo and adding it to an album, which would take an eternity. I've tried syncing to Google Drive before, but it is very inconsistent to the point of being unusable.)

There are several Google Product Forum posts regarding this. I've followed this active one for about a year with no resolution, and it is closed to further reply 3/1/18, though it has 8,000 views: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/photos/rJ_xWdcYB-A

This is a related post regarding a main problem of not having the tools to file photos into albums: [How can I view Google Photos that are not in a Google Photos album?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/82693/how-can-i-view-google-photos-that-are-not-in-a-google-photos-album)